# setup.exe file made by nsis was crashed on win10

Tags: crash, nsis

I have a setup.exe made by nsis, it works well on many computer, but crashed in splash screen on 2 computer,
all computer's os are win10.
I found crash log in system event log, it was report.wer, can somebody help me to find out how to fix it?

the log content below:
https://get.morelogin.com/Report.wer

Comment: already fixed, commented an unsing method call: `; Call SaInit`

Answer (score 0):

nsDui.dll is not an official NSIS plug-in. Remove it and see if the problem continues.

Post your code and I might be able to spot the exact problem...

Comment: thanks, already fixed, commented an unusing method call: ; Call SaInit